# What's the name of the highlight when you select "Get" and "Return" and "End Get" are highlighted?

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio

Sorry for the lame question, but I can't think of a decent way to ask.

When I have certain text selected, Visual Studio highlights certain other related text. If my caret is within "Get", the "Return" and "End Get" lines are highlighted. If I put the caret within the name of an instance, all references to it are highlighted. "If" highlights "Then" and "End If", etc.

This highlighting is weak and grey and shows up *really* badly on my screen and I was hoping someone could tell me what the name of the highlight it is in Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Fonts and Colors so that I can change it to something more eye-catching.

Any ideas?

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for "Highlighted Reference". At least in VS2010.

Comment: Cheers. Never would have gotten that from the name.